# How to slice using .writerow() in Python

Tags: python, datetime, csv, python-2.7

I'm having problems with the `writerow()` function. I have an object (orders_matrix) like this:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2008, 11, 20, 16, 0), 'AA', 'Buy', '100'],     
[datetime.datetime(2008, 11, 28, 16, 0), 'AA', 'Sell', '100'],
[datetime.datetime(2009, 2, 17, 16, 0), 'AA', 'Buy', '100']]
```

and would like to write it in CSV format like this:

```
2008,11,20,AA,Buy,100,
2008,11,28,AA,Sell,100,
2009,2,17,AA,Buy,100,
```

I've tried to use the `writerow()` function in a for loop:

```
with open('orders.csv', 'w') as orders_file:
  writer = csv.writer(orders_file)
  for row in orders_matrix:
    writer.writerow([row[:4], row[5:7], row[8:10], row[11:]])
```

but couldn't be able to convert the datetime object and add the other elements. I'd like to know if it's possible to do that and how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the year, month, day properties of the datetime object to get the related values. So, the last line might be changed with:

```
writer.writerow([row[0].year, row[0].month, row[0].day, row[1], row[2], row[3]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [datetime.timetuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.timetuple) to convert the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) object to a [struct_time](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) object and then slice out the required info, after converting it to a list

```
with open("orders.csv", "wb") as fin:
    writer = csv.writer(fin)
    for row in orders_matrix:
        writer.writerow(list(row[0].timetuple())[:3] + row[1:])
```